# Why leaf node with name type does not work in yang model?

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I have this simple yang model

```
leaf type {
    type string;
    description "some description";
}
```

This is not working. Can someone please explain if string 'type' is invalid for leaf name in yang?

Comment: pyang considers it to be valid leaf value.

Comment: Try enclosing the argument in quotes as a potential workaround. A tool that prevents such an argument to be used is not RFC7950/RFC6020 compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `leaf` statement argument must be an identifier and there is no restriction that prohibits usage of YANG keywords where an identifier is expected (all built-in keywords are also identifiers). Both `leaf type {...}` and `leaf leaf {...}` are valid YANG statements.

> The "leaf" statement is used to define a leaf node in the schema
> tree.  It takes one argument, which is an identifier, followed by a
> block of substatements that holds detailed leaf information.

> [RFC7950, Section 7.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.6)

Here's what the specification says about identifiers:

> Identifiers are used to identify different kinds of YANG items by
> name.  Each identifier starts with an uppercase or lowercase ASCII
> letter or an underscore character, followed by zero or more ASCII
> letters, digits, underscore characters, hyphens, and dots.
> Implementations MUST support identifiers up to 64 characters in
> length and MAY support longer identifiers.  Identifiers are case
> sensitive.  The identifier syntax is formally defined by the rule
> "identifier" in Section 14.  Identifiers can be specified as quoted
> or unquoted strings.

> [RFC7950, Section 6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-6.2)

The grammar rule mentioned above:

```
identifier          = (ALPHA / "_")
                     *(ALPHA / DIGIT / "_" / "-" / ".")
```

Here's what it says about the namespace of `leaf` statements (a namespace imposes a unique name requirement within its scope, with the purpose of preventing name clashes):

> o  All leafs, leaf-lists, lists, containers, choices, rpcs, actions,
> notifications, anydatas, and anyxmls defined (directly or through
> a "uses" statement) within a parent node or at the top level of
> the module or its submodules share the same identifier namespace.
> This namespace is scoped to the parent node or module, unless the
> parent node is a case node.  In that case, the namespace is scoped
> to the closest ancestor node that is not a case or choice node.

> [RFC7950, Section 6.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-6.2.1)